# how to return audioClip from yield return?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I want to write a method for loading audioClips from my

```
IEnumerator GetAudioClip(string filePath)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(filePath, AudioType.MPEG))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            AudioClip ac= DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);

        }
    }
}
```

I want my method to return audioClip
how can I do it? I looked into it some and there are some complex classes I dont get them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can't, due to the way coroutines were implemented in Unity.
There are several workarounds to this. Here are 2 off the top of my head:

## 1.IEnumerator coroutine which receives a variable delegate as a return method

```
IEnumerator GetAudioClip(string filePath, Action<AudioClip> callback)
{
    if (callback == null) { yield break; }
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(filePath, AudioType.MPEG))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
            callback(null);
        }
        else
        {
            AudioClip ac= DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
            callback(ac);
        }
    }
}
```

## 2.Use Unity's new async-await integration

```
public async Task<AudioClip> GetAudioClip(string filePath){

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(filePath, AudioType.MPEG))
    {
        var result = www.SendWebRequest();

        while (!result.isDone) { await Task.Delay(100); }

        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
        }
    }
```

Mind you this is pseudo code I have written in the browser, so it might not compile directly via copy paste.

Comment: thanks
and is there anything I should pay atention in calling these method?

Comment: @eomer I'm sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: Also, if this answered your question, please mark it as resolved

Comment: I've asked you how to call these method for 2nd way audioClip = GetAudio(filepath); didnt work I choosed your first way and call it like StartCoroutine(GetAudioClip(filePath, (result) =>{audioClip = result;}));
thx again

Comment: the 2nd method needs to be called from an async function and should be awaited. `public async void Foo() { var r = await GetAudio(filepath); }`